# ??? Undefined function or method 'det' for input arguments of type 'double' and attributes 'full 3d real

Tags: matlab, debugging, linear-algebra

```
for j=1:length(idf)
   dx = xf(1,j)- xv(1);
   dy = xf(2,j)- xv(2);
   d2 = dx^2 + dy^2;
   d = sqrt(d2);
   Z_est(:,j) = [d;atan2(dy,dx)-xv(3)];
   S(:,:,j) = Hf(:,:,j) * pf(:,:,j) * Hf(:,:,j)' + R
 end    

  v = zf - Z_est; %innovation
  v(2,:) = pi_to_pi(v(2,:));
  w= 1;
for n = 1:size(zf,2)
  den = 2*pi*sqrt(det(S));
  neu = exp(-0.5 * v(:,n)' * inv(S) * v(:,n));
  w = w*(neu/den);
end
```

my program is on computing weight of my state particles according to particle filtering,at the start it runs and calculate W,bt after sometime it shows error `??? Undefined function or method 'det' for input arguments of type 'double' and attributes 'full 3d real''` . 
I cant figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to give `det` a square matrix not a 3d one (`S` is a 3d array).
I assume you meant to write instead:

```
den = 2*pi*sqrt(det(S(:,:,n));
```

So at a given loop iteration the `det` of a slice of S is being calculated.

Comment: Thnakx...it solves my above error :),but becoz of that my other matrix gets high high dimension and shows error. thanku by the way...:)